# CppUnit tests integration in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I would like to create a Visual Studio 2022 project for existing UnitTests implemented for the CppUnit test framework. The tests should be visualized in the test explorer. The tests are additionally built in the Linux build environment.

In Visual Studio the plugin 'Test Adapter for CppUnitTestFramework' is installed. However, the plugin requires that the tests are implemented as follows:

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest3
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest3)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
        }
    };
}
```

But my existing CppUnit tests have the following structure:

```
class TestCases : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(TestCases);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(TestMethod1);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(TestMethod2);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
};
```

Is there another plugin for this? Or do I have to implement my own C++ macros that convert the format to the appropriate format for Visual Studio and gcc? I have searched long in Google but unfortunately did not get the overview.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

The [Test Adapter for CppUnitTestFramework](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drleq.CppUnitTestFrameworkAdaptor) is for use with the [CppUnitTestFramework](https://github.com/drleq/CppUnitTestFramework) single header library.  The code you are writing is for use with Microsofts own [Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2022), which happens to use the term `CppUnitTestFramework` in its namespace.  The two libraries are completely unrelated and it is a coincidence they were made publically available at a similar time.

Microsofts library has built-in support from Visual Studio 2019 onwards and does not require a third party extension for use with the Visual Studio Test Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

My code uses not Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++, it uses the CppUnit Framework: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/

I have not found a Visual Studio plugin for this framework. The naming is very confusing! ;-)